# xypic: Text inside square

Tags: positioning, xy-pic

I have a very basic square:

```
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d] & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}
```

What is the easiest way to place the text "hi" in the center of the square?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. In this group we love minimal working examples so we can try out your code immediately, without having to wonder about the required packages or having to type in the rest of your document. Providing a minimal example also shows that you've done some basic research.

Comment: For more information on minimal working examples, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 2):

```
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r] \ar[d] \ar@{}[dr]|{\mbox{Hi}}
  & B \ar[d] \\
  C \ar[r] & D
}
```

That adds in an invisible arrow (the `@{}` makes it invisible) going diagonally from the upper left to the lower right corner, and "breaks" the arrow with an \mbox containint the word "Hi".

Comment: Nice trick. How would you put the word at the position that is on the vertical line halfway between A and B, and the horizontal line that is twice as far from C as it is from A?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen -- this is cheating, and requires some guesstimating: replace the `\mbox{Hi}` by `\mathstrut\raisebox{1.5ex}{Hi}`. the strut is needed to establish a baseline, otherwise the box will be treated as an operator and vertically centered.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. The question was asked to show that  you (probably) needed some form of cheating to do this with `xypic`.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'm confused by your question, since the line between A and B is horizontal, and the one between A and C is vertical.  Anyway, you can drop the word anywhere at all using, e.g.,`\ar@{}[]+<2em,0ex>\txt{Hi}` to drop it 2em to the right of the current node.  (That draws an invisible arrow to the point and then drops a text object at the end of the arrow.)  See, e.g., "Getting up and running with AMS-LaTeX", page 36, at the end of section 8, from your favorite CTAN mirror.